# Understanding rc.local and troubleshooting

Tags: linux, rc

I (new to linux) am attempting to add a command to the boot up that will execute an application. The application accepts parameters and has simple output of what it is doing. To troubleshoot it, how can I see what the output is when it attempts to start up (or not start at all)? When I run the command, it works. Whend I add it to rc.local, I cannot tell why it is not working.

Comment: Of course, depending from your (unstated) flavour of Linux your system might well have far better mechanisms for starting daemons at boot time (or afterwards) and logging their output to an autorotated size-capped log that you have to do very little in order to set up; and `rc.local` may just be a backward compatibility shim.  You might profit from investigating those mechanisms instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/434276/1769):

> Unless a command has output or logging already configured, `rc.local`
>   commands will not log anywhere.
>
> If you want to see logs for specific commands, try [redirecting the
>   stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783341/run-script-with-rc-local-script-works-but-not-at-boot) for `rc.local` to somewhere you can check. Try
>   adding this to the top of your `/etc/rc.local` file.
>
> ```
> exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log      # send stderr from rc.local to a log file
> exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
> set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution
> ```
>
> Though this will require to rerun the `rc.local` file.

Comment: Can you test the edits to rc.local from a command prompt to see what is happening?

Comment: You can change to the directory containing the file and execute it as any other executable file.
  
`cd /etc/rc.d
./rc.local`

Comment: Apparently you are unable to put line breaks into comments so there are two commands you need to execute from your shell.  1st command = `cd /etc/rc.d` and the 2nd command = `./rc.local`  I hope this makes sense, hard to clarify with such limited markdown options :/ let me know if you need further clarification and I will make another answer

Comment: Also you can add the command `set -n` to the top of your rc.local file, this will do a syntax check to ensure your commands are syntactically correct, it will not actually execute the command.  You may also have issues executing rc.local after startup as some of the commands may already be running which will cause errors that otherwise may not have occurred when rc.local is run initially at start up.  DO NOT FORGET TO REMOVE `set -n` when you are done debugging

Comment: @Dylan +1 Good answer...About the interface here: You can edit your answer and indicate changes in the comments, you don't have to write a new one.  WRT multiple commands in comments, you can use semi-colons as you can in reality: `cd /etc/rc.d; ./rc.local`.  You don't have to cd for that, BTW, you can just `/etc/rc.local` from anywhere.

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` output will go to the console, so it should be visible; unless you're running e.g. openwrt where you don't have easy access to the console.

Comment: @wurtel `/etc/rc.local` is normally just a straight shell script, so run from the command line output will go to the controlling terminal like anything else, not the (system) console.

Comment: @goldilocks Awesome thanks for the tips, both very helpful for future posts!

Comment: The logging worked, the only question on logging left is how do you allow the subsequent runs to overwrite rc.local.log? I get permission denied when testing it at the console. It ran once though, and now I see my problem is pathing. In raspbian, I don't get the difference between '~' and '/' and how you switch between them. You can type 'sudo nano /etc/rc.local' from the ~ $ prompt, even though when I type 'ls', I do not see an etc folder. I realized you can type "cd /" to change to "/ $" but I do not understand the significance.

Comment: the `~` character is an "alias" for your home directory which is typically `/home/yourName` and the `/` character is known as your root directory similiar to c:\ in windows.  It is the bottom of your directory structure. `~ $` indicates you are in the home directory `/home/yourName` and `/ $` indicates you are in the root directory `/`. You use `cd` to change between directory locations. I would highly recommend you read [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucd.htm) for more information.

Comment: @goldilocks `/etc/rc.local` is meant to be run at the end of all other init scripts, and hence at the console, before you can log in. I has assumed that it was a given that output would appear at whatever terminal you run it manually from. I personally have never run it by hand.

Comment: @wurtel Yeah, *when run by init* at boot the output will appear wherever init directs it (probably either `/dev/console` or `/dev/tty1`, and the former tends to be synonymous with the latter).  But it's just a `#!/bin/sh` script.

Comment: syslogd is alive when rc.local is called. Use "cmd && logger -T RC_LOCAL cmd -> arbitrary message"