# Running an infinite loop on startup

Tags: startup, ping

I'd like to run a command at startup which pings a certain address every 10 minutes and writes the result to a file. I've figured out now how to do the pinging and file writing and the 10 min intervals:

```
while true; do my-command-here; sleep 600; done
```

My question is, can I put this in `/etc/init.d/rc.local` or should I be putting it in `/etc/rc.local` or somewhere else entirely? I'm specifically concerned because it's an infinite loop so I'm not sure if I could put it in one of these startup scripts.

Some help would be appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't really an infinite loop; it's a task that needs to run every ten minutes. As such the task can go into the task scheduler, `cron`.

Run the command `crontab -e` and add this single line to the bottom of the file:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/my-command-here
```

Ensure that `my-command-here` is an executable script (`chmod u+x my-command-here`) and that its first line starts with `#!` and the name of the script interpreter (typically `#!/bin/bash`).

Each entry in the pattern `*/10 * * * *` maps to the minute(0-59), hour(0-23), day(1-31), month(1-12), and day of week(0-6, with 0=Sunday).

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a much better idea. Just one question; Once I've added the line using crontab -e, do I need to restart the cron service or something? How can I check whether it is attempting to execute my script and perhaps fail?

Comment: The `crontab` command notifies the `cron` daemon automatically, so you don't need to worry about it. You can confirm it's working either by looking at the syslog (something like `grep -i cron /var/log/syslog`) or by modifying your program to write something to _stdout_ and then capturing that output something like this, `/path/to/my-command-here >/tmp/mch.log 2>&1`. If you don't capture the output it will be emailed to your local account.

Comment: +1 for answering the actual spirit of the question rather than the wording.

Answer (score 6):

> can I put this in /etc/init.d/rc.local or should I be putting it in /etc/rc.local or somewhere else entirely?

If you put it into `rc.local`, you should put it in a subshell and fork that into the background.  The last line of `rc.local` should be `exit 0`, and it not block, i.e., any foreground activities should be brief.

```
(while true
    do my-command-here
    sleep 600
done) &
```

The `( )` puts it in a subshell and the `&` puts it in the background.

If you have a problem, [check this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189411/understanding-rc-local-and-troubleshooting) about debugging `rc.local`.

Comment: BTW, you may want to include `echo $BASHPID > /tmp/myloop.pid` inside the subshell before the loop so you can check on that process later.  Or you could put it in a script somewhere, launch `myloop.sh &` from `rc.local`, and then you can find it by name.

Comment: Great answer. I'm still not sure though which of these rc.local scripts I should be using? Why would I choose /etc/init.d/rc.local over /etc/rc.local or vice versa?

Comment: Use `/etc/rc.local`.  `/etc/init.d/rc.local` is the SysV init service that actually runs the script at boot.