# Perpetually ping 3 devices from startup

Tags: cron, raspbian, ping

I wish to ping three local devices, every 5 min, without stopping, from a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian OS. When my Pi powers on, I want that to automatically start.

I saw an [old post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191646/running-an-infinite-loop-on-startup) about it, but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

As it is described in the answer you mention the best solution is to use cron. This is the record you need to have to run every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/shell_script
```

And the shell script itself can be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -q -c1 host1
ping -q -c1 host2
ping -q -c1 host3
```